# ValueWhenConverter and Enum

Tags: template10

How can I use the ValueWhenConverter with a enum?

For example:

```
<Grid Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.ViewModelStatus, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ViewStatusConverter}}">
..
</Grid>

<converters:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="ViewStatusConverter">
            <converters:ValueWhenConverter.When>
                <vm:ViewModelStates>Error</vm:ViewModelStates>
            </converters:ValueWhenConverter.When>
            <converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
            </converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
            <converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
            </converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
        </converters:ValueWhenConverter>
```

I don't think this syntax is correct: `<vm:ViewModelStates>Error</vm:ViewModelStates>`

How do I map the ValueWhenConverter to my enum values?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WhenValueConverter cant be map to enums, I tried using this:

```
<converter:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="EnumSexToBooleanConverter">
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.When>
            <vm:RegisterPageViewModel>
                <vm:RegisterPageViewModel.PersonalInfo>
                    <model:Personal>
                        <model:Personal.Sex>
                            0
                        </model:Personal.Sex>
                    </model:Personal>
                </vm:RegisterPageViewModel.PersonalInfo>
            </vm:RegisterPageViewModel>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.When>
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
            <ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch.IsOn>
                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                </ToggleSwitch.IsOn>
            </ToggleSwitch>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
        <converter:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
            <ToggleSwitch>
                <ToggleSwitch.IsOn>
                    <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
                </ToggleSwitch.IsOn>
            </ToggleSwitch>
        </converter:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
    </converter:ValueWhenConverter>
```

and it throws an InvalidCast exception, it is a good converter when using value types, such as x:Boolean, x:Int32, x:Double and x:String, also it has some enum values integrated in the xaml like visibility property which uses enums such as Visible and Collapsed.

as far as I try right now, and I even tried many different way, there is no way to use a WhenValueConverter with an enum.

If you need to make a conversion from a boolean to an enum and viceversa i suggest to create your own converter using IValueConverter.

That would be your best choice for your actual Issue.

Also if you wish to be able to map WhenValueConverter to your enum values it can be achieved by changing your viewmodel property to a dependency property like this:

```
public Gender Sex
{
 get { return (Gender)GetValue(SexProperty); }
 set { SetValue(SexProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SexProperty = 
 DependencyProperty.Register(
     nameof(Sex), typeof(Gender),
     typeof([YourContainerType]),
     new PropertyMetadata([initial_default_or_null_here])
 );
}

public enum Gender : int
{
  Female,
  Male
}
```

this is only an example and the author of this sample dg2k from the Template 10 github project.
[Template 10 - WhenValueConverter to Enum Values](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1555)